# Fill the Third Array by adding the elements of the First and Second Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, cartesian-product

I want to generate an array which content would represent a [*Cartesian product*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the two given string-arrays.

In other words, I need to concatenate each `String` from the first array `arr1` with every `String` from the second array `arr2`.

*Here is my code:*

```
String[] arr1 = {"a", "b", "c"};
String[] arr2 = {"d", "e", "f"};

String[] result = new String[arr1.length * arr2.length];

for (int k = 0; k < result.length; k++) {
    for (int i = 0; i <arr1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
            result[k] = arr1[i] + arr2[j];
        }
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

*Current Output:*

```
[cf, cf, cf, cf, cf, cf, cf, cf, cf]
```

*Desired Output:*

```
[ad, ae, af, bd, be, bf, cd, ce, cf]
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: So what is your expected output?

Comment: @nice_dev Pointed over the result array - [ad,ae,af,bd,be...]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the very first `for`-loop, it causes all the values in the resulting array to be overwritten multiple times.

Instead, you need to declare the index `k` of the resulting array outside the *nested loop* that generates the Cartesian product of the two given arrays. `k` should be incremented at each iteration step of the inner loop.

```
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
        result[k++] = arr1[i] + arr2[j];
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr3));
```

*Output:*

```
[ad, ae, af, bd, be, bf, cd, ce, cf]
```